# Algebraic closure for rings

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, modular-arithmetic, finite-rings

Is there any notion of algebraic closure for commutative rings? I am specifically interested in such a concept for $\mathbb Z_n$, with $n$ not a prime (possibly square-free).

Such a concept would be easy to develop for integral domains since these can be naturally embedded in their own fraction field. But what about rings having divisors of $0$?

I am also aware of the concept of integral closure of a ring $A$ in $B$, but this does not suit me because, unlike the algebraic closure for fields, the integral closure requires me to choose some auxiliary $B$, so this is a "relative" concept, not an "absolute" one.

If $n$ is square-free, could the fact that my ring is a product of fields simplify the job?

Comment: *the integral closure requires me to choose some auxiliary B* Why wouldn't you use the full ring of quotients in the role of the field of fractions? Of course, there are still some bad elements... but that supplies a canonical overring.

Comment: @rschwieb: Because that itself is not "closed", whatever that may be. But yes, that was the first option that crossed my mind. The second would be to consider the product $\overline {\mathbb F _{n_1}} \cdots \overline {\mathbb F _{n_k}}$ if $n = n_1 \cdots n_k$ is squarefree with distinct prime factors $n_i$. Also, the total field of fractions would only allow me to invert elements, but not to speak about square or cubic roots etc., things that form the "meat" of algebraic closures.

Comment: Oh I see what you meant now: a domain has its fraction field *and then its algebraic closure.* I only followed the thought halfway.

Answer (score 6):

One way to describe the algebraic closure is that it is in some sense a "maximal" algebraic extension: it's an algebraic extension into which every other extension embeds. So it seems to me like the following question is a more basic one that should be answered first:

> What's an algebraic extension of commutative rings?

There are various ways to answer this question depending on what you're trying to do. The simplest answer, generalizing finite extensions, is [finite morphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_morphism) of rings; this means that the map $f : A \to B$ exhibits $B$ as a finitely generated $A$-module. There are various notions of [Galois extension](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63741/is-there-a-galois-correspondence-for-ring-extensions) for commutative rings, and various corresponding Galois theories. And there is the notion of an [étale morphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tale_morphism), which leads to a Galois theory involving the [étale fundamental group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tale_fundamental_group).

I think with most of these definitions you'll run into the problem that there will in general not be a "maximal" such extension.