# Certain separable ring extensions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, integral-domain, flatness, separable-extension

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, $R$ a commutative $k$-algebra which is an integral domain having field of fractions $Q(R)$ and $a$ an algebraic element over $R$ ($a$ belongs to some algebraic closure of $Q(R)$, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291482/algebraic-closure-for-rings) question).

Let $h=h(T) \in k[T]$ be a separable polynomial of degree $d \geq 2$, namely, $h$ has $d$ distinct roots in $\bar{k}$ (= an algebraic closure of $k$).

Recall the definition of a [separable ring extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_algebra); according to wikipedia:
"Any separable extension A / K of commutative rings is formally unramified. The converse holds if A is a finitely generated K-algebra".

> Is it true that $A:=R[h(a)] \subseteq R[a]:=B$ is always a separable ring extension? If not, is it possible to characterize all $h$'s for which such extension is separable?
> What about flatness?

Notice that $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-algebra.

Special case: Is $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}] \subset \mathbb{Q}[3^{\frac{1}{4}}]$
separable? here
$k=R=\mathbb{Q}$, $a=3^{\frac{1}{4}}$, $h=h(T)=T^2$.

Remark: Maybe S.S.S Wang's [paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272332/1-s2.0-S0021869380X80025/1-s2.0-0021869380902331/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEMr%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIG4px3y%2BNt1%2BODJo40ahHKJoIvkRG%2BjLQYDbKaOoe8FuAiAx5hcVvjyFYx13jlgB%2F00mBr%2FgH128cp2RjMH0nvut1yq9Awiz%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAMaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMWLDWEN4DuHiXB%2BZ%2BKpEDyCFIFtjjh6FoWDK8PeVe4xcPaWsOUWdepc6zjqHnrr4lXT%2BJbnJH7eBHTYXkC4YPXMYT%2FtPEDAgTG%2BZSZG41eDqEV5%2FXzTMMK5QnQN1%2FlXoWMInsiumXRXvO%2FegLBYovOYBqKvLGCB3GV7E%2FvUbzRgD%2BSa0cHiQipLxr5HETq59aRfOW0OCcdiHFR6E8kgtIdltcqqKr8jnNMlWoo%2FuGIzSzLFH3VOzrVrgYVRWvq9jT%2BDjY5dKUt5PQsqMFiphBGE%2FwKyv1p5lMBv3Q8RkWzUBSNSrI0Bua29WklY1FPwCVrVlog63vY3ILppjqCeQDZzXXZ7Q97Xq3kMMyqrFEwg981oHFOobO0cX2F2hQUrv0elfnvgys%2F7rY6JhRrLIrMYIF8hnqOMcGVGn7gDK7pt31yYuDishLC3%2FrxLUSHZoC4P2HVOL%2FFMtFTXPajryaQyC3DQLQyc5LwVjLpAJR1yK1sCVnrwt%2Fg14%2Br3WV6s91W6a%2FoAiydzeeLv4pfs5RAbiLjiH6EZHnIZ3UnXMVhaowyNGR%2BgU67AGTV4agnOTdFBr82mez%2Fguai03%2F%2Fm33XegYpYaQ%2FpBP6%2FF3A03wAycrMq6%2Bjsje46Nkutdksy4RXCtbFFe8fPIdDBzhpH%2B4qnA5EjtIzFEAZlMTZaJFIDHDGKzMDjI7CiXX37cQtYRUWbyb4RxQlMskqOL%2FSQVlwlin3S5BnMckpImkqt7e8wQldjMBwEGOKbcQwPJUnkDeEglmX3EhFvoddQcOCaHD2sY8YKRWINU5aYwBWXZsjv8Jq1pIiyZQraLuimLHkzMCWFSfTscIu7L0ztz9LoT6oqZ1%2BScLGqrH%2Brv9K4miJH1yyR6Xzg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200825T020954Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY3XPZCFK3%2F20200825%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=29650ef3fd474c5129bb488d16337ff099f20ae677c9170154e1eb6bb69d86b7&hash=9eba88834c12bc8b657761e7338627e88afabe821bc585df32efacee88a8040e&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0021869380902331&tid=spdf-d3e7dfad-3cc4-42fe-abbf-82164fd827ef&sid=bbec5aad9825e24a078a86648acf17a03a57gxrqb&type=client) (Corollary 8,10) about separability is relevant here.

Any hints and comments are welcome! Thank you.

Comment: Wang's corollaries answer my question, if $A$ is a UFD, but not for an arbitrary integral domain $A$. Perhaps Theorem 5 answers my question.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}] \subset \mathbb{Q}[3^{\frac{1}{4}}]$
is not separable, by Wang's results, since $h(T)=T^2-\sqrt{3}$ is in the kernel of the relevant map (it generates the kernel), so $h'(T)=2T$ evaluated at $3^{\frac{1}{4}}$ does not generate the unit ideal in  $\mathbb{Q}[3^{\frac{1}{4}}]$.